# Challenge of the quran

Tags: quran, authenticity, challenge-of-the-quran

“If you are in doubt of what We have revealed to Our Messenger, then produce one chapter like it, call upon all your helpers, besides Allah, if you are truthful.” Surah al-Baqarah (The Heifer) 2: 23.

“Or do they say: “He (Prophet Muhammad, ) has forged it (this Qur’an)?” Nay! They believe not! Let them then produce a recitation like it (the Qur’an) if they are truthful.” Surah at-Toor (The Mount) 52: 33-34.

The challenge of the Quran, to create even a single chapter like it. To match its eloquence and grammar. Please enligthen me as to why this is impossible. Not being an arabic speaker i cannot speak to this. However i have read many books in english that are gramatically correct and very elegant in their use of language.

Comment: It is not only about eloquence or grammar, but also due to many factors it is hard to produce a chapter like it.

Answer (score -3):

Well Brother Allah says in Chapter 4 He says "And if this Quran came from anyone else, they would have found many errors in it." The Quran mentions recent scientific discoveries like the moon being reflected light and how every living thing was made from water. No one could have even known this 1400 years ago. But anyways the point is If the Quran was forged or came from human beings, then that would mean other human beings would be able as well to produce something similar to that. So if the Quran was forged then other human beings can produce a book similar to it. Shakespeare usually makes one or two literary devices in every verse. However If you look at the shortest Surah in the Quran, Surah Kauther which has 3 verses only, has more than 30 literacy devices. So that is why the challenge is impossible.

Comment: This answer really doesn't have much in the way of details.  Explaining *what* these alleged 30 literary devices even *are* may be the start of an okay answer, but as written it's so vague as to be useless.

Comment: The fact that a piece of literature is so impressive doesn't tell us anything about the impossibility of duplication by a man. And even if it was impossible to duplicate by a man and we could demonstrate that, that doesn't therefore allow us to conclude that therefore the Quran is miraculous and is of divine origin. Also, what is the criteria for producing something like it anyway and who decides this?