# Has anyone historically accepted and tried Allah's challenge?

Tags: quran, challenge-of-the-quran

The Qur'an challenges people to bring something similar to it.

All of the people I know including myself read these verses and think "then this is a divine book, because nobody can bring something similar".

Do we have any historical record of a person or group actually accepting that challenge, spending time and energy on it, (and failing of course) after delivering their writings which have persisted till now.

Please note that I've seen this question already:

[Challenge of the quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20245/challenge-of-the-quran)

My question is not about **why** but about historical evidence.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure plenty of people attempted. However, one that I know of is by Christian evangelists. They called it “The True Furqan.”

I am sure you can find it online.

Obviously, it does not do anything close to beating the challenge. In fact, a lot of it is just a copy of the Quran changing a few words to fit their message and theology. In this imitation, they, ironically, prove that the Quran’s style is superior such that even a text trying to challenge it has to resort to the Quran.

Also see here: [Does "The True Furqan" meet the Quran's challenge?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36045/does-the-true-furqan-meet-the-qurans-challenge)